# How to do batch rendering in pixi.js

Tags: pixi.js

I'm looking for help with [batch rendering](https://pixijs.io/pixi-batch-renderer/PIXI.brend.BatchRenderer.html). I understand it batches together objects such as sprites, graphics, etc for performance purposes. I have a very large number of objects to display.

However, the only assistance I found was [this](https://medium.com/swlh/inside-pixijs-batch-rendering-system-fad1b466c420) which is so hard to follow. Are there any simple tutorials or guidance out there for this? Ideally, I want a very simple example that batches together 2 sprites and renders them in one draw call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spoke to the creator of pixi-viewport and he said that pixi has batching built in.

Performance improvements were instead gained by:

- Using pixi-cull (a good perf boost if you are also using pixi-viewport)
- Switching from Graphics to Sprites
- minimising the use of sprite.interactive = true
- using text.renderable = false when text is zoomed out (again zooming relates to pixi-viewport)